# Can we subscribe to more than one thing while using http request in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

Sending form data with the help of angular http client and now i want to subscribe to not only event but also the data coming back from the server. The event is used for displaying the progress bar and the data is what i want to display it to the user. This is the code snippet:

```
const req = new HttpRequest('POST', url, newFormData, {
    reportProgress: true,
    responseType: 'text' as 'json'
  });

  // create a new progress-subject for every file
  const progress = new Subject<number>();

  // send the http-request and subscribe for progress-updates

  this.http.request(req).subscribe(event => {
    if (event.type === HttpEventType.UploadProgress) {
      // calculate the progress percentage
      const percentDone = Math.round(100 * event.loaded / event.total);

      // pass the percentage into the progress-stream
      progress.next(percentDone);
    } else if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
      // Close the progress-stream if we get an answer form the API
      // The upload is complete
      progress.complete();
    }
  });
```

So here i am able to subscribe to the events and its working good but i also want the response data that the server sends back. Is there a way to subscribe to both the event and data objects. Please help!

Comment: Have you tried official sample for progress event, https://stackblitz.com/angular/keqqadexmvq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fuploader%2Fuploader.service.ts

Comment: Just found out that i can use the entire response object to do exactly what i want. Thanks anyway!!

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
import { forkJoin, of } from 'rxjs';
...

forkJoin({
      a: this.httpservice1.(params).pipe(catchError(error => of(error))),
      b: this.httpservice2.(params).pipe(catchError(error => of(error))),
      c: this.httpservice3.(params).pipe(catchError(error => of(error))),
}).subscribe(({ a, b, c }) => 
var aux = a.body.info
})
```

ForkJoin will wait for all the request to be done before running the subcription